# A Problem for measure function $n(y)$，the number of solution

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f(x)$ be a real measurable function defined on $[a,b]$. Let $n(y)$ be the number of solutions of the equation $f(x) =y$. Prove that $n(y)$
is a measurable function on $\mathbb{R}$.
Considering f(x)=a is measureable and discuss the  counting measure of it？

Comment: Are you allowing the possibility that $n(y) = +\infty$?

Comment: @GregMartin I have not consider that.But I think it should make no difference.